# Calculating $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0+}}{\frac{3e^{\log^3x}\log^2x}{x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have problem to calculate this limit:

$$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0+}}{\frac{3e^{\log^3x}\log^2x}{x}}$$

Here's what I've tried:

$$\begin{aligned} \displaystyle{
\lim_{x \to 0+}}{\frac{3e^{\log^3x}\log^2x}{x}} &= 
3\lim_{x \to 0+}{e^{\log^3x + 2\log(-\log x) - \log x}} \\
&= 3e^{\lim_{x \to 0+}{\log^3x + 2\log(-\log x) - \log x}}
\end{aligned}$$

Maybe not best approach, but here is where I am stuck.
I don't know how to simplify limit here, as it's in indeterminate form $-\inf + \inf$

Thanks.

Comment: It must be useful to note that you're trying to calculate the limit of the derivative of $e^{\log^3 x}$.

Comment: Yes that's true.

Comment: Multiply by $x^2$ in the denominator and numerator and use $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x\ln x = 0$. Then to calculate the limit $e^{\ln^3(x)}/x^3$, use the substitution $\ln(x) := u$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thanks, updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=e^{-t}$, then $$L=\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{3t^2}{\exp{(-t+t^3)}}.$$
By two times L-Hospital, $$L=\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{6t}{(3t^2-1)\exp(t^3-t)}=\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{6}{6t\exp(t^3-t)+6t(3t^2-1)\exp(t^3-t)}=0$$

Comment: Why $exp(-t + 3t^2)$ in the first expression? Shouldn't be $exp(-t + t^3)$. Because by substitution: $e^{log(x)} = e^{-t}$, then $-t = log(x)$, then $e^{log^3(x)} = e^{-t^3}$

Comment: Thanks, yes I have corrected it now.